# Hugo page build failure on github (not jekyll)

Tags: github, netlify, hugo

I'm new to web development, so please bear with me.

I'm build my blog project on github, I'm not user jekyll, I'm using "Hugo" and deploy by "Netlify", at this several days,I'm still push my change to github, but some problem shows:

---

The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

The symbolic link `/content/images` targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#symlink-does-not-exist-within-your-sites-repository.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

---

My every commit on GitHub all get the errors, I've tried make a empty file.nojekyll in the root, but still not getting better, I've check the Hugo file, but it host and deploy on GitHub not Netlify, so I think maybe it's irrelevant with my errors.

Here is my repo:
https://github.com/Luke1760/MyBlog

Appreciate your answer previously.

Answer (score 2):

```
The symbolic link /content/images targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository.
```

The `/content/images` points to `/Users/joway/Code/frontend/hugo-blog/static/images/`, which tells me you are a Mac user :). But the Netify doesn't have any idea where to get your images from. This *would* work, should you build your site locally on your Mac.

Comment: @LukeDai would you mind accepting it as an answer (tick next to upvote/downvote controls)?

Comment: @badishop ofc, you deserve it !